# Pass columns and selected rows from one GridView to another across Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, gridview

I have a DataGrid1 in one Form and a second one in another Form2. Now I wanted to pass rows which I select in one GridView to the second one.

```
public String selectRows(object sender)
    {
        string val = String.Empty;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in form1.dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            dataGridView2.Columns.Add(column.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in form1.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            int index = dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row.Clone() as DataGridViewRow);
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Value = cell.Value;
            }
        }

        return val;
    }
```

this works when both GridViews are in the same Form (and the code is changed a bit without "sender", "val" etc). Now above I tried to establish a communication between both forms. In this case I get a "NullReferenceException" on

```
  dataGridView2.Columns.Add(column.Clone() as DataGridViewColumn);
```

I also made a function in Form1:

```
 public Object getDataGrid()
    {
        return dataGridView1.DataSource;
    }
```

and tried to set "Object gridData = form1.getDataGrid();"
When I now try to write "gridData.Coulumns" he won't accept the "Columns". What can I do or is the function not valid?

Comment: You can define a list property in code behind of second form and fill it by selected rows while opening second form.

Comment: Isn't it possible to move the whole Data Table to the other GridView? How do you mean that?

Comment: @MKX2015 does both forms display at a time?

Comment: Yes it is possible see the answer and let's have a discuss to complete that.

Comment: Yes. I select some rows in GridView from form1 and then pass them to GridView in form2. So Form2 opens and I can see both GridViews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a property as `DataTable` in `Form2`
if you wanna to move whole `DataTable` to `Form2` when you are opening `Form2` fill the property like:

```
    Form2 f2= new Form2();
    //f2.DataTableProp= yourDataTable;
    f2.ShowDialog();
```

see the commented line.

Or you can follow these steps:

1- Add a property to `Form2` like this:

```
public List<DataGridViewRow> Rows
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

2- In `Form1` when you want show `Form2` like this:

```
 private void btnShowForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            selectedRows.Add(row);
        }
        Form2 oForm = new Form2(this);
        oForm.Rows = selectedRows;
        oForm.Show();
    }
```

3- At the end you can manipulate `Rows` in `Form2` like:

```
private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Rows)
        { 
            //Manipulate row
        }
    }
```

The above steps are tested and works properly.

But based on your question and your code I see you want to access selected rows of `Form1` GridView, so from what I know an added control on a win form is private
for this reason you can change access type of `GridView1` to Public like:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
```

and then you can pass `Form1` as parent of `Form2` in it's constructor something like this:

1- Change the constructor of `Form2` like:

```
public Form2(Form1 parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        //You can access gridView1 here
        //For example 
        MessageBox.Show(parent.dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString());
    }
```

2- When you open `Form2` passe `Form1` as it's parent like:

```
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
        f2.Show();
```

Or:

```
public Form1 ParentForm
    {
        get;
        set;
    } 
    public Form2(Form1 parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ParentForm = parent;
        selectRows();
    }
    public void selectRows()
    { 
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in ParentForm.dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            //Your code
        } 
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ParentForm.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
             //Your code
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I just want to move dynamically the selected lines. When both GridViews are in the same form, the code above works correctly.

Comment: @MKX2015 you want to pass Form1 GridView rows to Form2 , right ?

Comment: I had this already like you posted it but with a new constructor Form2(Form1 form1). When I put "Form1 parent" into the constructor where he initializes the Components it gets messed up. Then he can't even call the function from Form1 anymore. When I create a new object GridView2 in my Select Rows functions the Exception disappears but he opens an empty Form Window. Why? Otherwise there is this NullReference at dataGridView2

Comment: Ok sorry that was my fault. I forgot something. Now your first one works and he opens my form when I click the button but the GridView2 stays empty. No Exception, nothing at all.

Comment: So do the first trick, define a property in From2 and fill it when it's opened.

Comment: I bet you did something wrong again, maybe you must execute `selectRows` method for example in `Form2_load` or `Form2_Shown`.

Comment: Ok it was my fault again. I had a line "DataGridView dataGridView2 = new DataGridView();" and forgot to delete that. Now it works fine! Thank you for your help!